# How to increase font top-margin?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I´m trying to remove the margin added to the top/bottom of my font.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="text">Text</span>
</div>

#wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  Border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#text{
  background: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

[image]

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/fsmje7Ly/1/

How can i increase the red background to the font height?
How can i remove the top/bottom margin from the font?

I´ve tried playing with `line-height: 30px;`

Comment: Have you tried to set `margin: 0;` on  `body` element? After setting `margin: 0;` on `body` set `#text` to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Just replace the <span> with a <p> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code you will get the desired ouput.

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  Border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#text{
  background: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `display: inline-block;` to your css - it will remove mentioned padding.